# How to just load inner view in Phoenix framework?

Tags: ajax, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Elixir in Phoenix framework.We know when we call an action in controller, the framework render a full view that includes footer, inner view ( main content) and header. How to load and render  just a view without header, footer view ?

Example : localhost:4000/posts/new 
-> We will have header, form and footer

localhost:4000/post/1
-> We just show content of post #1 without header and footer view.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11):

You need to use [`Phoenix.Controller.put_layout(conn, false)`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#put_layout/2) in your controller action function to disable rendering the layout, e.g.

```
def show(conn, _params) do
  conn
  |> put_layout(false)
  |> render("show.html")
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Dogber. It works.  I also wrote the code:  render conn,"show.html", layout: false

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please accept his answer as correct.